# Determine values of a point based nearest point values - QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, fme-form

I have some weather stations that receive and publish precipitation data every day.
Then I have polygons (can be center points if necessary) that correspond to interest areas.

I want to estimate the precipitation for each area with the stations within a maximum buffer of the center point.

It's not possible to use the default interpolation tools because the stations not always surround completely the polygons.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I would do a spatial join of the points and the areas, joining the area of the polygon to the point, and then create an extra attribute multiplying the precipitation/m² and the total area(m²)

Answer (score 1):

In FME the NeighborFinder transformer will tell you the nearest station to each polygon, and the PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer will tell you which stations fall inside a polygon.

If you want to interpolate a value then I think the best thing is to create a surface model (use the SurfaceModeller transformer) draping the polygons onto the surface generated by the weather stations. You'll have to first make sure the stations are 3D points with Z set to the precipitation (3DForcer transformer) then you'll have to fetch the Z values from the draped polygons (CoordinateExtractor transformer).